# clipping two objects

Tags: modeling

I would like to know what's the best way to model complex objects in Blender when i need to clip to objects together. Should I alter the mesh or just let them clip?

**Examples**

Altered mesh
[image]

Clipping
[image]

Comment: You can make them clip if the render doesn't make any difference

Comment: If you clip two objects, their border will have a sharp edge in any case, if you alter them, you can use smooth shading, but most of the cases it doesn't matter.

Comment: @FFeller but whiich is better for game assets ?

Comment: @LuizCarlos The one requiring less geometry, therefore not modelling the intersection. If both objects are static meshes and its meant for a game, then you really do not need to model it (or only in circumstances where it allows to use fewer polygons).